# Consulta en SQL de campos mas repetidos

Tags: php, sql

Estoy haciendo un sistema de tienda (SQL, PHP) y en una Query en sql quería que me devolviera en la tabla de ventas los 5 artículos que mas se venden:
La tabla de ventas contiene los siguientes campos:

> id, código del articulo, descripción, precio de venta, fecha, hora

tengo esta consulta:

```
select * from ventas group by codigo
```

pero esta me devuelve todo el contenido agrupado en la tabla no los items mas repetidos

Comment: Puedes poner los demás campos de la tabla ventas?, para poder orientarte mejor

Comment: Hola, claro son: id, código del articulo, descripción, cantidad, precio de venta, categoría, cajero, fecha, hora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta de esta manera

lo que hacemos es agrupar por producto (como lo tenias), pero, también sumamos las cantidades.

con el TOP decimos que solo queremos 5 registros

con el ORDER BY DESC ordenamos de mayor a menor

```
SELECT TOP 5 codigo,SUM(cantidad) cantidad
FROM ventas
GROUP BY codigo
ORDER BY cantidad DESC
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!, y desconocía lo de TOP, nuevamente muchas gracias